# Force a GNUstep "bundle" to be executable

Tags: objective-c, bundle, gnustep

Does anybody know how to get GNUstep-make to compile a bundle but make the resulting binary executable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out at least one way to do it (perhaps the only way).  Override BUNDLE_LDFLAGS:

```
BUNDLE_LDFLAGS =
```

Probably not the best way but it worked for me.